# Maven for other languages?

Tags: java, maven-2, project-management, build-process

I am relatively new to the world of Java and Maven, but I couldn't imagine starting a new Java project without using Maven.

The idea of providing a human-readable project model is something that I would imagine is universally desirable across many languages. This is especially true when your application relies upon numerous external libraries.

Are there any other project management or build tools for languages other than Java that are similar in nature to Maven; that is, that provide a mechanism for the project maintainer to specify dependencies and build order?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's some I know of. As to whether they are the most appropriate tool for a given language, form your own opinion.

- .Net: [NMaven](http://incubator.apache.org/nmaven/) and [dotnet-maven-plugin](http://doodleproject.sourceforge.net/mavenite/dotnet-maven-plugin/index.html)
- AspectJ: [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) (still Java I know but worth mentioning)
- c/c++: [native-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/) compile with compilers such as gcc, msvc, etc ...
- Google Web Toolkit [gwt-maven-plugin](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/)
- PHP: [Maven for PHP](http://www.php-maven.org/)
- Ruby: [Ruby on Maven](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rubyscript-maven-plugin/introduction.html)
- Scala: [maven-scala-plugin](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/)
- Flex and Air: [Flexmojos](http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/)

Arbitrary "integrations" can be handled by using the [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to invoke the relevant compiler and binding the execution to the compile phase.

There are also Maven-like products such as [Byldan](http://www.codeplex.com/byldan/) for .Net

---

Updated with Flex Mojos and dotnet-maven-plugin at [Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70604/pascal-thivent)'s suggestion.

Comment: I didn't wanted to edit your answer. Could you add http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/ for Flex and Air. Ever heard of http://doodleproject.sourceforge.net/mavenite/dotnet-maven-plugin/index.html for .NET?

Comment: @Pascal, you should feel free to edit any answer if you can make it better, that's what this site is for

Comment: @Rich Ok, thanks. I'm just still not sure about the edit etiquette. Will browse meta for this :)

Comment: I'd say adding to a list like this wouldn't (well shouldn't) offend anyone. For general etiquette see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26237/

Comment: Don't forget Groovy, gmaven-plugin http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Building+Groovy+Projects

Answer (score 3):

Python [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) works in a similar way to Maven in so far as specifying project dependencies. If the dependencies specified are available as eggs, tars or zip files then they can be automatically pulled in at installation or runtime.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need fancy plugins to manage just about anything that can be executed from command line. As an example I have put Maven builds around poorly managed .NET projects using technics [described in this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20110830022107/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Using+Maven+to+manage+.NET+projects). Basically - plugins such as `exec`, `antrun`, `assembly` and `dependency` can be used together as I mentioned - to do practically everything you need.
Of course there are specialized, targeted plugins but I found out that these are hard to use with existing legacy stuff

Answer (score 2):

I know that there are a couple of Maven plug ins for compiling GWT, [gwt-maven](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-maven/) and [gwt-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/).

There's also this the [maven-scala-plugin](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/).

I'm sure if you do a search, you'll find it for most popular JVM languages.

And of course, there's [NMaven](http://incubator.apache.org/nmaven/) for .NET. I've never used it though.

Comment: Right, it's easy to see how Maven can be used for JVM languages other than Java. Most of what you referenced are plugins to Maven. What I'm looking for is more along the lines of Byldan ( http://byldan.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Documentation%20%280.5%29 ), which seems to be equivalent (but not equal) to Maven for C# projects. I found this application via your NMaven link.

Answer (score 1):

Phing is the PHP equivalent to Ant.  It's (obviously) not quite Maven, but PHP doesn't have the same library (jar) management issues that Java does.