# Using maven for perl projects

Tags: perl, maven, maven-plugin

We have seen Maven perform very well for our Java-based projects. I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168960/maven-for-other-languages) that non-java projects can also be retrofit as maven modules, albeit they will only be using the maven-exec-plugin for different goals. On googling, I saw [maven-perl-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-perl-plugin) but it is still a 1.0-SNAPSHOT with sporadic updates, but certainly looks very promising. Has anyone used this one or any other competitor which will relieve me of writing non-interesting pom boiler-plate?

EDIT: Actually the major part of the project is the n-tiered Java modules and there is a very small perl/python component (for backend parsing) and I am looking for a place to fit it into this ecosystem. I get advantages like using maven-release-plugin to do tag/branch creation and release processes and having it as a part of the same codebase gives me version number consistency. So while I don't intend to use dependency retrieval means of maven for perl modules (sorry that I didn't research enough on the maven-perl-plugin boy), I wanted to know what are the points to be kept in mind when doing such a thing (or if such a thing doesn't make sense) e.g. what should be the module name (*topLevelModuleName*-perl?) and the structure beneath src/main/perl and src/test/perl. I know I might be going down a slippery slope trying to shoehorn one thing to the other, but doesn't hurt to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point, I am inclined to not use maven-perl-plugin for its dependency feature because it seems to have overlap with much well-established peers like Dist::Zilla and Module::Build. Since no one really commented on the edit, I am left with maintaining the existing project structure like

```
<perl-module-name>
    -lib
    -etc
    -bin
```

and not really changing anything other than add a pom file with the tarball being created as the output artifact.

Feel free to post any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

That's crazy. Use something sane like Module::Build and for dependencies use CPAN (or cpanm). Seriously, for anything that's not Java you have to write load of XML for load of crazy plugins. With Module::Build (or any script) you program your build and you can use any library that's available for the language (you just need to get them with cpanm before).

Comment: @Kilokahn Packaging Perl modules is not fun and best left to the dedicated tooling developed to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a quick glance at this plugin and I don't see the point of pulling in dependencies like Java and XML just to manage your project.

Actually I think that we already have something **much** better: [Dist::Zilla](https://github.com/rjbs/dist-zilla/). Setting up your project is as easy as `dzil new My::Project` - and `Dist::Zilla` takes care of everything else.

No more Makefiles, READMEs, MANIFESTs... Just type `dzil build/test/install/release` and everything will be done according to your profile and `dist.ini`.

And if you are missing some dependencies from CPAN, add this to your config and [cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/module/App%3a%3acpanminus) can be integrated smoothly into your new workflow.

```
[alias]
    instdeps = install --install-command "cpanm ."
```