# Why does Java Standard Directory need a directory named "Java"?

Tags: java, maven

From https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html I can see that there is a directory `/src/main/java` .

Why do we need a directory named `java` here? Do we have another programming langeage within a java project?

Comment: You might. `scala` for example. But you should (or could) also have a `/src/main/resources`.

Comment: Scala, Groovy, Kotlin, etc JVM based languages that Maven could compile

Comment: 'Do we have another programming langeage within a java project?'. Your question is mis-phrased. It should be 'Do we have another programming langeage within a *Maven* project?', and the answer is yes, Java is only one of many possible choices.

Comment: You also have non-language directories, e.g. `/src/main/resources`, `src/main/webapp`, ... Since there are multiple directories, the one with the Java source code needs *some* name, so why not `java`, even if other languages weren't possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we need a directory named java here?

To allow for other languages.

> Do we have another programming language within a java project?

Potentially yes.  Systems with components written in multiple languages are common.  There is no insurmountable technical reason why Maven should / could not also build the non-Java components, especially when the languages can be compiled to bytecodes.

By specifying a location for Java source code, the Maven designers have (at least) avoided future problems.

**UPDATE**

Indeed, this is not hypothetical:

- http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_compile.html ... which uses "src/main/scala" and "src/test/scala".
- [Maven for other languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168960/maven-for-other-languages)

Another use-case is for the input files for generators / translators such as idlj and javacc.